# Change multiple column names in SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am using `SQL Server 2012`. I have created a `View` but I have done one mistake. I added columns like `Column_Name1` `Column_Name2`..........

But I had to add them like `Column Name1` `Column Name2`........

There are about 300 columns so I need a way to replace `_` by white space in column names. Please suggest me fast way.

**Edit**

People are down voting without any reason, I guess because it is the view of 300 columns, forget about view. What if it would be a table?

Thanks

Comment: View with 300 columns seriously

Comment: press `ctrl+F` replace `_` to `whitespace` then click on `Replace All`

Comment: Why do you want spaces in your column names? You will need to do more than just replace underscores with a space. You will now have to also wrap each and every column in square brackets because of the space.

Comment: I agree with @Fireblade, a view with 300 columns sounds completely ridiculous.

Comment: Why down-vote? Any one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GO TO **SSMS**->**Server**->**YourDataBAse**->**Views**->*Select your view*->(Right click)-> **SCRIPT VIEW AS** -> **ALTER TO** -> **New Query Window**. Then use the basic CTRL+H for Search and Replace. Then Run the Script.

Hope I understood right what you want. This is the easy and fast way.

Comment: It will change those columns also that are part of physical table and I will have to embrace all columns. It will be even more costly

Comment: Yeah, but you can use CTRL+H and don't use the Replace All, just go THROUGH all the column using next, and if you want to replace the _ use replace.

Comment: My design view will provide lot faster way

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Retrieve the view definition
2. Drop the view
3. Modify the view definition (using your favorite editor ... mine's "vi") to replace "_" with " ", adding quotes for your column names
4. Recreate the view